# Is there a way to VACUUM an sqlite3 database in parts to avoid OperationalError: database or disk is full/reduce size of sqlite3 databse

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

I have a rather large sqlite3 database that I've built/populated through python over a few months. I have done many inserts/deletes etc while putting it together and it now uses the majority of my diskspace so I don't have enough disk space left to add a required index/do other things I need to do on it.

I found out about the `'VACUUM;'` command which sounds like it will help reduce the disk space my database uses, however as it makes a copy it needs more spare diskspace than I have to run it (I have already deleted as many other files as I possibly can).  Is there any way to run the VACUUM in bits/chunks to avoid needing so much spare disk space? Or are there any other things I could do to help reduce the size of my database?

Comment: How about `VACCUM INTO SomeTempPath` to get a new and vaccumed db in another internal/external drive? Then replace the original with it. Note, the original db remains _unvaccumed_ this way. See [VACUUM with an INTO clause](https://www.sqlite.org/matrix/lang_vacuum.html).

Comment: @dr.null Thanks for the idea! unfortunately I don't think I'll be allowed an external device for security reasons, and shared drive won't be big enough

Comment: I see. Then tell the security guy that you can't beat the physics. If you don't have enough space to have the temp db during the `VACCUM` process then you need some `VOODOO` cmd rather than `VACCUM`.

Comment: typo correction... `VACUUM` is.